# Knockout value binding to HTML5 date picker (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, knockout.js

I noticed in a Knockout binding to an HTML5 date input, that the binding was firing whenever a key was pressed when typing into the control. This is in contrast to the regular `<input type="text"/>` box where the value only causes the observable to update when focus is lost, or enter is pressed.

I believe Knockout by default is using the change event, and so for a simple example of how this behaves without Knockout, I produced a small fiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/qm282xdm/).

You can see that the input text box doesn't fire the change event until you lose focus or hit Enter on the box, but if you type a new date into the `<input type="date"/>` then every keystroke causes the change event to fire.

Is this supposed to behave this way? The differing behaviour of the text vs date input is a little counter-intuitive. I'm running Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 and I have a feeling an older version behaved more like I am expecting, but I can't be sure.

Edit: I would like to know if this is a problem with Chrome or 'by-design'. The firing of the change event is intuitive on a text type input, and I would expect it to be the same from a date type input. In the absence of any ideas on how to work around this, I will write a custom binding that fires in the cases I expect.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what kind of answer you're looking for. If the question is just "is it supposed to behave this way?" then the answer is "yes". The answer to "Why?" is a bit less clear.

If you want to make them a bit more consistent, you can use the [`textInput`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) binding instead of the `value` binding, which ensures you get immediate updates from textbox bindings. Or, with older versions of knockout, use `value` binding with `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'`.

Comment: Point taken. I'm after whether this is the way the control is supposed to behave, and if not, how to work around the bug. Unfortunately, what you suggest doesn't give me the behaviour on the date control I want, which is that similar to the <input type="text"/>, it would only fire the change on loss of focus, or hitting enter.